# How to view full model's center of mass?

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I know that you can view the center of mass for each link, but how can I graphically see the center of mass for the full model? If no tool for this is available, how should I approach creating my own? (I'm guessing that this is what a plugin would be for, right?)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24575/how-to-view-full-model%27s-center-of-mass?/) by [Victoria Bentell](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16040/victoria-bentell/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo doesn't provide this functionality out of the box. You could create a model plugin which calculates the CoM and publishes a [marker](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/3ca3431cfe5a/examples/stand_alone/marker/) at that position.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2020-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1